# Why is $P(T=\infty)>0$ from $\sum X_{n}$ converges a.s.?

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

> Suppose $\sum X_{n}$ converges a.s. and $|X_n| \leq K$. Define
>   $T:=\inf\{\tau:|M_{\tau}|>c\}$ where $M_{\tau}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$.
>
> Then why is $P(T=\infty)>0$ for some $c$?

Since $\sum X_{n}$ converges a.s., the partial sums of $\sum X_{k}$ are
a.s. bounded, and it must be the case that for some $c$, $P(T=\infty)>0$.

I don't understand what the above line is saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

$$Y(\omega) := \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|M_n(\omega)| = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left| \sum_{j=1}^n X_j(\omega) \right|.$$

By assumption, $Y$ takes (almost surely) values in $\mathbb{R}$. Since

$$1= \mathbb{P}(Y \in \mathbb{R}) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|Y| \leq k)$$

we can choose $k>0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(|Y| \leq k)>0$. If we choose $c:=k$, then

$$\{|Y| \leq k\} = \{\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: |M_n| \leq k\} \subseteq \{T=\infty\}$$

and so

$$\mathbb{P}(T=\infty) \geq \mathbb{P}(|Y| \leq k)>0.$$